# What's the HTML semantic structure of multiple titles with each single related list?

Tags: html, title, semantic-markup

I have a directional section on which it describes the address, phone #, email, and service date/time.

I would like to have it look like below ex:

[image: list structure]

My code currently looks like this:

```html
<div class="content">
  
  <section>
    <h2>address:</h2>
    <p>123 Beach rd. Brakersville IL, 60054</p>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <h2>phone:</h2>
    <p>(555)555-5555</p>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <h2>email:</h2>
    <a href="#">madeupemail@gmail.com</a>
  </section>
  
  <section>
    <h2>service:</h2>
    <p>Fridays - 7:30pm to 8:30pm</p>
    <p>Sundays - 11am to 1pm</p>
  </section>
  
</div>
```

I used the title `<h2>` to relate to this following sibling `<p><a>` tags, all wrapped in a `<section>` tag so that it doesn't relate to any other sibling sections.

To me the code looks wrong. Is their a better way to approach this or is it fine? Also is the use of `<section>` tag correct?

Comment: I think since they're all part of the same chunk of information, that they actually _should_ relate to each other. If you just want them to be separate visually, wrap the chunk of information in a div like `<div class="chunk">` (or whichever class you want) and use CSS to separate the `<h2>`s.

Comment: You should use a definition list (`<dd>`) for key value pairs like this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `section` element is a sectioning content element, i.e., each `section` creates an entry in the document outline (same thing if you’d omit the `section` but keep the `h2`).
But this is probably not what you want, especially not if the content is so short (e.g., just a telephone number).

You could use a [`dl` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) instead:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Address</dt>
  <dd>…</dd>

  <dt>Phone</dt>
  <dd>…</dd>

  <dt>Email</dt>
  <dd>…</dd>

  <dt>Service</dt>
  <dd>…</dd>
</dl>
```

(Although perhaps the opening hours should not be part of that list because all other items are about contact details.)

Comment: Should i then put the service as `<h2>` and it's opening info out of the `<dl>` tag in its own wrapped `<div>`? Or not wrapped and keep it outside as a sibling level where the `<dl>`'s at

Comment: I would go with a `section` (+ heading) for the opening hours if the `dl` with the contact details is also placed in a `section` (+ heading), e.g.: `<section><h2>Contact details</h2> …</section> <section><h2>Service</h2> …</section>`. -- But if it works for you to use the same `dl`, don’t worry and just keep the service in there, too.